# To find $R\circ R^{-1}$ in Discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Today I came across a question in DMS which says:

> If $R$ is the relation “Less Than” from $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to $B = \{1,3,5\}$ then find $R\circ R^{-1}$.

Now what is $R\circ R^{-1}$?

I know how to find $R\circ R$, 
like in this question firstly we will find $R$ where

$$R= \{(1,3),(1,5),(2,3),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5)\}$$

and then $R\circ R$ would be:

$$\{(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5)\}.$$

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
And also please explain how to find $R\circ  R^{- 1}$?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: why do you think that RoR is {(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5)} ? I thought it would be {(1,5),(2,5)} ?

Comment: @ Nils Ziehn , please explain .

Comment: I edited towards legibility and hope I matched what was intended

Comment: After executing $R$ once, you are either at $3,4 or 5$ and when you then execute $R$ again, you have to go from $3, 4 or 5$, but from $4$ and $5$ you have nowhere to go, right? Therefore you can only chose the ones that lead to $3$, which are $1$ and $2$ for a starting point and will both lead to $5$ at the end

Comment: If you are familiar with relation matrix , write that relation matrix named by M,then find M*M ,then each element of matrix is not zero substitute by 1 , then write relation from matrix again ,it is RoR

Comment: Am I right? I'm a little confused.. sry!

Comment: OK, Thanx @  Nils Ziehn

Comment: Is it always $(R\circ R^{-1})$ and not $(R\circ R)^{-1}?$

Comment: I think for my question it is ( (R∘R−1) and not (R∘R)−1. But i'm not sure

Comment: $\mathrm{ran} R = \left\{ 3,\, 5 \right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R\subseteq A\times B$, $S\subseteq B\times C$ are relations, then $S\circ R\subset A\times C$ is given by $$S\circ R=\{\,(a,c)\mid\exists b\in B\colon aRb\land bRc\,\}. $$
(So as a side remark, your example calculation of an $R\circ R$ is wrong, cf. Nils Ziehn's comment).
Moreover $R^{-1}\subseteq B\times A$ is the reverse relation, given by
$$ R^{-1}=\{\,(b,a)\mid aRb\,\}.$$
Putting these togeher, $R\circ R^{-1}$ is a relation $\subseteq B\times B$ and specifically
$$R\circ R^{-1}=\{\,(b_1,b_2)\mid\exists a\in A\colon a<b_1\land a<b_2\,\}. $$
Can you write that down explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is correct..
$$R\circ R=\{(1,5),(2,5)\}$$
therefore
$$R\circ R^{-1}=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)\}$$
or simpler
$$R\circ R^{-1}=\{(a,b)|a,b \in 1,2,3,4\}$$

Comment: Not what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna introduce the *domain* and the *range* of $R$, which are defined in *Elements of Set Theory* by Herbert B. Enderton:

\begin{align}
x \in \mathrm{dom} R &\Leftrightarrow \exists y :\: \left( x,\, y \right) \in R,\\
x \in \mathrm{ran} R &\Leftrightarrow \exists t :\: \left( t,\, y \right) \in R.
\end{align}

[image]

It'll help you think.

---

Because $ R = \left\{ \left(1,\,3\right),\;\left(1,\,5\right),\;\left(2,\,3\right),\;\left(2,\,5\right),\;\left(3,\,5\right),\;\left(4,\,5\right) \right\} $.

We can get $\mathrm{dom} R = A = \left\{1,\,2,\,3,\,4\right\}$, and $\mathrm{ran} R = \left\{3,\,5\right\}$.

To get $R \circ R$, evaluate $\mathrm{ran}R \cap \mathrm{dom}R = \left\{ 3,\, 5 \right\} \cap \left\{ 1,\, 2,\, 3,\, 4 \right\} = \left\{ 3 \right\}$, use the elements of it in the second $R$. It's obvious that the only possible routes are $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 5$ and $2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 5$, i.e. $R \circ R = \left\{ \left(1,5 \right),\, \left( 2,\, 5 \right) \right\}$.

By definition, $R^{-1} = \left\{ (y,\,x) \mid xRy \right\}$. So $R^{-1} = \left\{ \left(3,\,1\right),\;\left(5,\,1\right),\;\left(3,\,2\right),\;\left(5,\,2\right),\;\left(5,\,3\right),\;\left(5,\,4\right) \right\} $.
$\mathrm{dom}R^{-1} = \mathrm{ran}R = \left\{ 3,\,5 \right\}$.

Similarly, to get $R \circ R^{-1}$, evaluate $\mathrm{ran}R \cap \mathrm{dom}R^{-1} = \left\{ 3,\,5 \right\}$. Therefore we can get $R \circ R^{-1} = \left\{ \left(1,\,1\right),\;\left(2,\,2\right),\;\left(3,\,3\right),\;\left(4,\,4\right),\;\left(1,\,2\right),\;\left(2,\,1\right),\;\left(2,\,3\right),\;\left(3,\,2\right),\;\left(3,\,4\right),\;\left(4,\,3\right),\;\left(1,\,3\right),\;\left(3,\,1\right),\;\left(2,\,4\right),\;\left(4,\,2\right),\;\left(1,\,4\right),\;\left(4,\,1\right) \right\}$.